# Deleting empty rows on if the row in Column D is empy

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I im trying to work on scripts that deletes the entire row if the Columnd D has no information in that row (specailly at the buttom part). here is my script that im trying to work on but im getting this error.

```
function removeEmptyRows(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var maxRange = sh.getRange('D3:D27');
  var maxRows = sh.getMaxRows();
  var lastRow = maxRange.getLastRow();

  sh.deleteRows(lastRow+1, maxRows-lastRow);
}
```

THE ERROR: Exception: Those rows are out of bounds.
removeEmptyRows @ Code.gs:47

i did find a working solution in the internet but it was using a for loop, which takes a lot of time to delete the rows if the rows is like 100+. Here is a sample screenot if how shout it work
*PS. sorry for bad english*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qxqJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```
function removeEmptyRows() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var maxRange = sh.getRange('D3:D27');
  var maxRows = sh.getMaxRows();
  var lastRow = maxRange.getLastRow();
  if (maxRows > lastRow) {
    sh.deleteRows(lastRow + 1, maxRows - lastRow);
  }
}
```

Comment: dudeeeee man, it works! holy crrap thanks man!

Comment: at first i thought it didnt work, and it was because i was running a different functions. thanks man. never though adding the if statement is the key.

Comment: last question i deleted the range static range to D3:D to make it dynamic but it didnt work. is there any solution to that? it looks like i should have been much clearer in my question.

Comment: If you use ranges like D3:D you should always include the lastRow like "D3:D" + sh.getLastRow()

Comment: Thanks, man for this, i tried it, and its working fine but there's just one last thing. I tried putting data on column A on rows 28-33, i was expecting it to delete the entire rows below Column D 27 that has no information but it didn't, it stop deleting at A33, i cant upload any screentshots but hopfeully i did interpret it properly. So to summarize delete the entire rows on columnd D1:D that has no information regardless if the other columns has data.

Comment: Did you read my last comment?

Comment: I did, i did as well add the D3:D" + sh.getLastRow()
here is the final scripts.

function removeEmptyRows() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var maxRange = sh.getRange('D3:D'+ sh.getLastRow());
  var maxRows = sh.getMaxRows();
  var lastRow = maxRange.getLastRow();
  if (maxRows > lastRow) {
    sh.deleteRows(lastRow + 1, maxRows - lastRow);
  }
}
it deleted only the rows with entirely no data, but when i start adding data on Column A28-33, it stop the deletion at A33, even though the last row on column D is row 27.

Comment: hey man! i found a working script for the final scenario.
 
function removeEmptyRows() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var maxRange = sh.getRange("B2:B" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var lastRange = maxRange.filter(String).length + 1;
  var maxRows = sh.getMaxRows();
  if (maxRows > lastRange) {
    sh.deleteRows(lastRange + 1, maxRows - lastRange);
  }
}